# Transform dataframe based on ID status

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
    USER_ID MONTH       STATUS_ID
0   23026   2019-09-01  2
1   23026   2019-10-01  2
2   23026   2019-11-01  2
3   23026   2019-12-01  2
4   23027   2019-09-01  2
... ... ... ...
123 16546   2018-10-01  2
124 16622   2018-09-01  1
125 16622   2018-10-01  1
126 16622   2018-11-01  1
127 16622   2018-12-01  1
```

All users should have 4 rows (4 Months) but period can be different
(01.02.2018 -01.05.2018 or 01.02.2019 - 01.05.2019 ...)

and I would like to transform like this

```
    USER_ID MONTH_1 MONTH_2 MONTH_3 MONTH_4
0   23026   2       2       2       2
1   23027   2       2       2       2
... ... ... ...
123 16546   2       2       1       1
124 16622   1       1       1       1
```

and the last thing I should transform dataframe based on STATUS ID

```
    USER_ID ID
0   23026   2    
1   23027   2    
... ... ... ...
123 16546   2
124 16622   1
```

That is a kind of boolean operation between ID's in different Months.
Any idea of how to transform this? Or could this be solved more efficiently?

Comment: Can yiou be more specific for `and the last thing I should transform dataframe based on STATUS ID` ?

Comment: That is what I have to get at the end of the transformation. Probably that can be done directly -using 'transform'

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is `Month_4` ?

Comment: It seems I miss the point. The goal is to transform dataframe at the beginning to the last dataframe, grouped by USER_ID and boolean operations ´or´  between ID

Comment: hmmm, what means `OR` ? Because data are not boolean, but numeric `1,2`... Can you explain more?

Comment: You are right, 2 and 1 are ID statuses for Churn. I have to at first transform into boolean data and then perform logical operation. For example:
2 and 2 and 2 and 2 = 2 ( not churn)
2 and 2 and 1 and 1 = 1 (churn) 
1 and 1 and 1 and 1 = 1 (churn)

Comment: hmmm, not sure if understand. What does mean churn? Is possible simplify it by last value of column, here `Month_4` ?

Comment: This code is part of churn prediction use case so '2' means that user will not churn and 1 will churn.  When the user has only one month in status '1' (churn) that means the final status is '1'.  THe final status '2' is possible only whan the user has all months in status '2' (not churn). That 's why I have to use logical operations on STATUS ID.

Comment: So is possible say if there is at least one `1` per rows then output is `1`, else `2` ?

Comment: That's right. I have more rows per each USER_ID with possible different statuses.  Then I have to transform STATUS_ID into boolean data (2 into ' Not true' and 1 in  into 'True') and if it is possible I can run transformation directly on rows (logical operation OR on STATUS_ID for each user)  or create pivot table and then run logical OR operation on columns. The results should be dataframe with USER_ID and final status

Comment: Answer was edited, can you check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think possible solution is create new column by counts with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and pass to [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df)
     USER_ID       MONTH  STATUS_ID
0      23026  2019-09-01          2
1      23026  2019-10-01          2
2      23026  2019-11-01          2
3      23026  2019-12-01          2
123    16546  2018-09-01          2
123    16546  2018-10-01          2
123    16546  2018-11-01          1
123    16546  2018-12-01          1
124    16622  2018-09-01          1
125    16622  2018-10-01          1
126    16622  2018-11-01          1
127    16622  2018-12-01          1

df['MONTH1'] = 'MONTH_' + df.groupby('USER_ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df = df.pivot('USER_ID','MONTH1','STATUS_ID')
print (df)
MONTH1   MONTH_1  MONTH_2  MONTH_3  MONTH_4
USER_ID                                    
16546          2        2        1        1
16622          1        1        1        1
23026          2        2        2        2
```

Then compare by `1` by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), last `map` and convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df1.eq(1).any(axis=1).map({True:1, False:2}).reset_index(name='ID')
print (df1)
   USER_ID  ID
0    16546   1
1    16622   1
2    23026   2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1.eq(1))
MONTH1   MONTH_1  MONTH_2  MONTH_3  MONTH_4
USER_ID                                    
16546      False    False     True     True
16622       True     True     True     True
23026      False    False    False    False
```

Comment: I would recommend not to perform a groupby when you can just rename a sorted array of dates. It will be slower on a huge dataframe.

Comment: @ionpoint - It seems you miss `(01.02.2018 -01.05.2018 or 01.02.2019 - 01.05.2019 ...)`, your solution here is not possible

Comment: @jezrael tnx, a lot. That is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"USER_ID": 23026, "MONTH": "2019-09-01", "STATUS_ID": 2},
        {"USER_ID": 23026, "MONTH": "2019-10-01", "STATUS_ID": 2},
        {"USER_ID": 23026, "MONTH": "2019-11-01", "STATUS_ID": 2},
        {"USER_ID": 16622, "MONTH": "2019-09-01", "STATUS_ID": 1},
        {"USER_ID": 16622, "MONTH": "2019-10-01", "STATUS_ID": 1},
        {"USER_ID": 16622, "MONTH": "2019-11-01", "STATUS_ID": 1},
    ]
)

pivoted = df.pivot(index="USER_ID", columns="MONTH", values="STATUS_ID")
# Sort column names
pivoted = pivoted.reindex(sorted(pivoted.columns), axis=1)
pivoted.columns = ["MONTH_" + str(x) for x in range(1, len(pivoted.columns) + 1)]
print(pivoted)
# if you want USER_ID as a regular column use:
# pivoted = pivoted.reset_index(col_fill="USER_ID")
```

Comment: tnx that is a good solution but in my case, there are different months in the period so I got more than 60 months in pivot table. And I have to use boolean opetaror between id's

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as to the format of the first column of your final output.

Adjust these two scripts as needed:

It is required, that each id has always 4 lines. Also first user / last user may be skipped.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                  

import csv                                                                                           

prev_id = 0                                                                                          
sc = 0                                                                                               
buf = [0, 0, 0, 0]                                                                                   

with open("test.csv") as f:                                                                          
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)                                       
    for row in data:                                                                                 
        if sc == 4:                                                                                  
            print(int(row[0]) - 4, prev_id, buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3])                          
            sc = 0                                                                                   
        else:                                                                                        
            prev_id = row[1]                                                                         
            buf[sc] = row[3]                                                                         
            sc += 1
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                  
import csv                                                                                              

prev_id = 0                                                                                             
prev_stat_max = 0                                                                                       
counter = 0                                                                                             

with open('test.csv') as f:                                                                                                             
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)                                          
    length = sum(1 for row in data)                                                                     

with open('test.csv') as f:                                                                             
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)                                          
    for row in data:                                                                                    
        if prev_id == row[1]:                                                                           
            if row[3] > prev_stat_max:                                                                  
                priv_stat_max = row[3]                                                                  
        else:                                                                                           
            print(counter, prev_id, prev_stat_max)                                                      
        prev_id = row[1]                                                                                
        prev_stat_max = row[3]                                                                          
        counter += 1                                                                                    
        if counter == length:                                                                           
            print(counter, prev_id, prev_stat_max)
```